# How can I declare types on object keys

Tags: typescript

```
type MyType = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'

const myObject = { foo: 'val1', bar: 'val2', baz: 'val3'}
```

How can I define a type that represents an object whose keys are of type `MyType` ?

Comment: you can create an interface/class with the types

Comment: @mast3rd3mon we can do better that having to restate all the keys if we already have a union of them :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir `MyType` is never used (from the small code we have) so it would make more sense to change it into an interface/class

Comment: @mast3rd3mon what people usually post is a small minimum example of what they are trying to achieve my guess is this is parte of a larger code base. I doubt the OP has not considered a simple interface.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir it appears to me that the OP hasnt considered using an interface at all, it is also probably the best way to proceed as it also allows for the interface to be using in other files/places

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I added a caveat suggesting a simple interface if there is no other use for the union of keys, for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to go from a union of keys to an object type where all the keys are of a given type. There is actually a predefined mapped type called `Record` that will do this job:

```
type MyType = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'

const myObject: Record<MyType, string> = { foo: 'val1', bar: 'val2', baz: 'val3' }
const myObject2: Record<MyType, string> = { foo: 'val1', bar: 'val2' } //error baz missing
const myObject3: Record<MyType, string> = { foo: 'val1', bar: 'val2', baz : 0 } //error baz of type number
```

`Record` will take a union of keys and create a type where all the keys have the type that is specified by the second type parameter, so  `Record<MyType, string>` equivalent to `{ foo: string, bar: string, baz: string }`

**Note**:

If you have no other use for the union of keys, you are probably better off with a simple interface:

```
interface MyObjectType { foo: string, bar: string, baz: string }
const myObject: MyObjectType = { foo: 'val1', bar: 'val2', baz: 'val3' }
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote ? Feedback  is appreciated :)

Comment: Neat, I didn't remember that `Record` was part of the language, I always used `{ P in K }` every time T_T

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I always tend to not use the predefined mapped types too .. I was also thinking of doing `{ P in K }` and after I wrote it rememeberd about `Record` :)